# Admissibility necessary for a $(\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{k})$-module to be a direct sum of simple $\mathfrak{k}$-modules?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, definition, lie-algebras

I am now looking over the book A. Borel, N. Wallach, *Continuous Cohomology, Discrete Subgroups, and Representations of Reductive Groups*, Volume 67 of Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, AMS. I would like to ask the relationship between the admissibility as a $(\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{k})$-modules and being a direct sum of simple $\mathfrak{k}$-modules.

Let $F$ be a commutative field, $\mathfrak{g}$ a finite dimensional Lie algebra over $F$, $\mathfrak{k}$ a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. The book says in Chap. I, 2.2 that a $\mathfrak{g}$-module $V$ is a $(\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{k})$-module if it is locally $\mathfrak{k}$-finite and is semisimple as a $\mathfrak{k}$-module. In the same section, such $V$ is defined to be *admissible* if its isotropic subspaces for $\mathfrak{k}$ are finite dimensional. The book says that if this is the case, then it is a direct sum of simple $\mathfrak{k}$-modules.

Why is the admissibility necessary here? I guess the last claim is a consequence of the fact that $V$ is a semisimple $\mathfrak{k}$-module by the definition of $(\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{k})$-modules.

Comment: What's the definition for a semisimple module here in case it is not finite dimensional?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Actually, I cannot find that in the book. The definition in my mind was the one on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module . Is there a possibility that infinite dimensional modules cause problems?

Comment: Well, all definitions I know for semisimplicity of finite dimensional modules over a Lie algebra are equivalent to saying that they are isomorphic to a direct sum of simple modules. So indeed the admissibility creiterion would be redundant here. But I know that as soon as one allows infinite dimension, some definitions are no longer equivalent to each other, and I wondered if this might be the case here. If we take the WP definition, and by modules mean modules over the universal enveloping algebra, things are still equivalent. That's why I wondered if the book uses different definitions.